# Primality test for specific class of $N=k \cdot 2^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can you prove or disprove the following claim:

> Let $N=k \cdot 2^n+1$ be a natural number that is not a perfect square such that $ 2 \nmid k$ , $n>2$ . Let $c$ be the smallest odd prime number such that $\left(\frac{c}{N}\right)=-1$ , where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes a Jacobi symbol . Let $z$ be a real number of the form $a+b\sqrt{c}$ equal to the modular $(1-\sqrt{c})^{(N-1)/2} \operatorname{mod} N$ , then $N$ is prime iff $a=b$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtj9EKgyAUhu97jHZz3IxlY1fhI-wVgmEGUnpMDRZj7z4zWhsMRD3H___P5yEz_HqsmsuJ1Rm2rXVKSzCEPzt0ayH4hSJS1UHv0EjRSweCRgkvGHUyTM6AIITUr8yPLoj18YYtPGjam6pYWqTO9Kz8PkHPYPmgugCLjBWr-wuCptUAmIKRc7XMiBQWB4EynpRFhr0qyUbDPrcyYUWT8n6c7i6lxngTIBeoLXoVZE6Wz_2wcbapUiv_Z4rRb2V2Zwc=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). I have verified this claim for all $k \in [1,1000]$ with $n \in [3,1000]$ .

Comment: This looks rather similar to the [Proth test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem) for the same type of number.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Note that  there is condition $k<2^n$ in Proth test.

Comment: This should be equivalent to simply $(1-\sqrt{c})^{(N+1)/2}$ having a zero $\sqrt{c}$ coefficient.

Comment: Also, where are you using $k$ and $n$? If it just that $N$ must be $1\bmod 8$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I wrote number $N$ in the given form because of condition $n>2$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails for $N=22577=1411\cdot 2^4+1=107\cdot 211$. The value of $c$ that is taken is $3$, but
$$(1-\sqrt3)^{11288}\equiv 11502+11502\sqrt 3\bmod 22577.$$
It is true, however, if $N$ is prime. Setting $x=\sqrt c$, we have that $x^N$ is the Galois conjugate of $x$, so $x^N=-x$, whence
$$(1+x)^{N+1}+(1+x)^N(1+x)=(1+x)(1+x^N)=(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2=1-c;$$
this is a product of $-1$ and primes strictly less than $c$ (including $2$) and thus a quadratic residue (using that $c\equiv 1\bmod 8$), so
$$(1+x)^{\frac{N+1}{2}}\in\mathbb F_N;$$
this implies that
$$(1+x)^{\frac{N+1}{2}}=(1-x)^{\frac{N+1}{2}},$$
which gives that, if $(1-x)^{\frac{N-1}{2}}=a+bx$ with $a,b\in\mathbb F_N$,
$$(a-bx)(1+x)=(a+bx)(1-x)\implies x(a-b)=x(b-a)\implies a=b.$$